# How do I open a spring bean definition in intellij?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-13

I know this is possible using the gutter icon if you are already in the associated class, but is there a way to open a particular bean definition by its name in the same way that ctrl+n will open a class file? This is supported in SpringSource Tool Suite, so I would have thought there was an equivalent in IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

And you can select the bean definition. You can also select only bean definitions to include.

Also, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> enables you to search shortcuts